# How to expand a given set to form a basis for vector space $P^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $P^3$ denote the vector space containing all polynomials with degree less than or equal to $3$.

Given a set of finite elements, say, $2$, how exactly do we expand the set to form a basis for $P^3$? What are the parameters we're supposed to use?

Comment: It's the vector space containing all the polynomials with degree less than or equal to 3

Comment: Finite means countable, elements means one of the distinct objects of the set. Hence finite elements would be defined as countable number of distinct objects in the given set

Comment: The space is $4$-dimensional. You have $2$ elements. Assuming these $2$ are linearly independent, you need $2$ more.

Comment: Yeah I know that. I want to know how to determine the other two elements. Assuming the given two are linearly independant

Comment: Try to find vectors orthogonal to the $2$ given vectors. This boils down to solving a system of $2$ linear equations in $4$ variables.